# Python Try and Except Statements Custom and Normal Exception Output

Tags: python, exception

When throwing an exception how do I get the compiler to throw my custom exception AND the compiler exception.
Here is an example of what I want to happen

```
def func_A(int)
    try: 
        ans = 1 + int 
        print(ans)
    except:
        print('Oops your input was wrong')

def func_B(int)
    ans = 1 + int 
    print(ans)
```

Input_A:

```
func_A('Hello_World')
```

Output_A:

```
'Oops your input was wrong'
```

Input_B:

```
func_B('Hello_World')
```

Output_B:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-fe7d28575c18>", line 2
def func_B(int)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Desired Output:

```
'Oops your input was wrong'

File "<ipython-input-5-fe7d28575c18>", line 2
def func_B(int)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#errors-and-exceptions) in the Tutorial.

Comment: Your example is missing colons at the end of the function definition statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `raise` to the end of your except to raise the exception again, like this:

```
def func_A(int):
    try:
        ans = 1 + int
        print(ans)
    except:
        print('Oops your input was wrong')
        raise

func_A('Hello_World')
```

Output:

```
Oops your input was wrong
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashish/s.py", line 15, in <module>
    func_A('Hello_World')
  File "/home/ashish/s.py", line 3, in func_A
    ans = 1 + int
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted.